# Firestore onSnapshot listener's initial data fetching is slow

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to build a React chat app using Firestore. In the component where I render messages, I have the below code to subscribe to the chatMessages sub-collection

```
const endTime = new Date();

useEffect(() => {
 const unsub = subscribeChatMsg();
 return () => {
  unsub();
 };
}, [chatId]);

const subscribeChatMsg = () => {
const q = query(
  collection(db, "chats", `${chatId}`, "chatMessages"),
  orderBy("timestamp", "desc"),
  limit(30)
);

return onSnapshot(q, (querySnap) => {
  const messages = [];
  querySnap.forEach((doc) => messages.push(doc.data()));
  const sortedMessages = messages.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.timestamp === null) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (b.timestamp === null) {
      return -1;
    }
    return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
  });
  setChatMsg(sortedMessages);

  const endTime = new Date();
  const timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
  console.log(
    `Time taken to fetch Firestore data: ${timeTaken} milliseconds`
  );
});
```

};

But it takes about 800ms for the listener to make the first update (when the component is first mounted or is re-rendered when the chatId of a chat room changes and the listener is detached and re-attached). Subsequent updates remain fast if the dependancy doesn't change.